# How to add interactive charts in Excel?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to add the below interactive chart in excel. But using the below example chart is not rendered inside the excel. I'm trying for interactive charts which is there in the excel using JavaScript. I have attached the below image from excel. I need to draw a chart like below, when I hover on it, it should show the data on it. Whenever there is a change in table data, chart should be automatically updated. This is the feature in excel, how to incorporate the same in JS code. Please help me to add the interactive chart in excel with respective table data.

[image]

```js
        function exportToExcel() {
            var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
            var chartCanvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
            var ctx = chartCanvas.getContext('2d');

            // Extract data from table
            var data = [];
            for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                data.push({
                    month: row.cells[0].innerText,
                    revenue: parseFloat(row.cells[1].innerText)
                });
            }

            // Create chart
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: data.map(function(item) { return item.month; }),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Revenue',
                        data: data.map(function(item) { return item.revenue; }),
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // Generate Excel file
            var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
            var ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(table);

            // Add chart image to Excel
            var chartDataUrl = chartCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var chartDataBinary = dataURItoBlob(chartDataUrl);
            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Data");
            XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'chart_with_data.xlsx');
        }

        // Function to convert data URI to blob
        function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
            var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
            var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
            var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
            var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            return new Blob([ab], { type: mimeString });
        }
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Interactive Chart in Excel</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.4/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.5/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Revenue</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>10000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>12000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>15000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<button onclick="exportToExcel()">Download Excel</button>
```

Comment: I am getting a console error in the snippet I made you - there is btw a newer version

Comment: I have added the correct snippet but still when I'm saving the above code in html and hitting in browser excel is downloaded but no chart is inserted inside it. I don't want canvas image , I just need the interactive chart functionality whichever there in excel. same functionality needed using JavaScript

Comment: https://excelchamps.com/excel-charts/interactive-charts/#Sample_File---this is the example how can I get the interactive chart in excel. I need the same implementation in JS